# how to use paging in displaying records from the database?

Tags: php

I am displaying some records from the database. Currently I am displaying the top twenty records but I want to show all records with twenty records per page.

How will I use the paging in php to display all records?'

Any Idea about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [paging with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117342/paging-with-php) (First result for [php paging](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+paging), because there is nothing conrete in your question to go by.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
$posts_per_page = 10;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 0;
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM <table> LIMIT %d, %d", 
                  $page * $post_per_page, 
                  $posts_per_page);
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

The above query will select 10 records with a offset based on the current page.
You will also have to get the total number of pages based on the `$posts_per_page`:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM <table>";
```

You will have to keep track of the total number of posts divided with `$posts_per_page` and also the current page, then you can display a prev and next link:

```
if ($current_page > 0) {
   echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . ($current_page - 1) . '>prev</a>';
} 
if ($current_page < $max_pages - 1) {
   echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . ($current_page + 1) . '>next</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to send a page variable, for example `$page`, to your script and then customize your MySQL query to retrieve only that page's results.

Here is an example so you can see what I mean:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$resultsPerPage = 20;
$start = ($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage;
$query = "SELECT `results` FROM `table` WHERE ... ORDER BY `date` LIMIT $start, $resultsPerPage"
```

You can see how if `$page = 1`, then `$start = 0` and this query will retrieve the 20 results, offset at 0. For `$page = 2`, `$start = 20` so the query will retrieve the results from 20 - 40, which should show on the second page.

This is assuming your first page is 1. If you want the first page to be 0, then you need to change `$start`:

```
$start = $page * $resultsPerPage;
```